# C# - Arduino Serial Communication freezes(?) while reading Data

Tags: c#, arduino, serial-port

My program checks on startup if an Arduino is connected, and if that's the case, it sends a test message via Serial Port to see if it responds correctly. It then waits for the result, and if the answer is "success", it continues starting up.

Here's the important part of the code:

```
...
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Threading;

namespace ProFlagControlApp
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        static AutoResetEvent autoEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);

        ...
        private SerialPort arduinoBoard = new SerialPort();
        private string ardAnswer;

        /// <summary>
        /// Automatically detect the COM port on which an Arduino is connected.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>If an Aduino is connected, the port is returned as a string. If not, it returns null.</returns>
        private string AutodetectArduinoPort() { ... }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializing communications with the Arduino.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="port">The identifier of the port the Arduino is connected to. Example: 'COM4'</param>
        private void OpenArduinoConnection(string port)
        {
            if (!arduinoBoard.IsOpen)
            {
            arduinoBoard.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(ArdSerPort_DataReceived);
            arduinoBoard.BaudRate = 115200;
            arduinoBoard.PortName = port;
            arduinoBoard.Parity = Parity.None;
            arduinoBoard.DataBits = 8;
            arduinoBoard.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            arduinoBoard.Handshake = Handshake.None;

            arduinoBoard.Open();
            }
            else
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("port is already in use");
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The event handler for receiving data from the Arduino.
        /// </summary>
        private void ArdSerPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            string data = arduinoBoard.ReadTo("\x03"); // Read Arduino data until exit code
            ardAnswer = data.Split('\x02', '\x03')[1]; // Only save information between the start and exit code
            autoEvent.Set();
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            ...

            // Detect if Arduino is connected, shutdown the application otherwise.
            if (AutodetectArduinoPort() == null) { ... }

            OpenArduinoConnection(AutodetectArduinoPort());

            // Test Arduino communication
            arduinoBoard.Write("connection#");

            autoEvent.WaitOne(500);
            if (ardAnswer != "success")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error communicating with Arduino", "Control Unit Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
                Application.Current.Shutdown();
                return;
            }

            ...
        }

        ...
    }
}
```

I checked via the Arduino Serial Monitor if the command is read correctly and the appropriate response message is written into the Serial Port, which is the case.

However, the `ArdSerPort_DataReceived` event is never triggered. When I try to manually put a `ardAnswer = arduinoBoard.ReadTo("\x03");` before it tests what is in the `ardAnswer` variable, the program seems to freeze and does not continue with anything.

I am really wondering why. I have to admit that I haven't touched this program for quite a while now, but when I last worked on it, it all behaved as it should, with the exact same code.

Comment: Your SerialPort initialization code is inadequate.  You must also set Parity, DataBits, StopBits (none, 8, 1).  And the important one, Handshake must be None since Arduino does not implement the handshake signals.  Not setting it produces a random value that depends on prior usage of the port.  The ARE is risky, but as long as the Arduino only ever sends something when you ask for it then you'll get away with it.  Not using DataReceived at all is far more sensible.

Comment: Changed it in my code, thanks. Didn't help the main problem, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer. C# / Visual Studio / .NET Framework / Whatsoever doesn't seem to like high baud rates. I turned it down from 115200 to 9600 (standard as far as I know), and now everything works as it should. Strange.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have a race condition:  when you open the serial port (on most systems), the change in the DTR/RTS serial port signals will reset the Arduino.  That, in turn, will cause the bootloader to run, wait for a short period to see if there's any code to load.  If not, it drops into your program.

My guess:  you are sending your test command while the bootloader is waiting, causing some or all of your command to get lost.

Try:  adding a delay (few seconds to start) after you open the port and before you send your command.

Even better:  have your Arduino code send a response or print a banner of some sort when it first starts.  Then, have your C# code wait for that **after** opening the serial port, so you know that the Arduino has reset, gone through the bootloader, and your code is now fully up and running.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't fix it. The bootloader doesn't seem to run either when opening the serial port, as I can't see the Arduino LEDs flashing, which they normally do while booting(?)

Comment: If you change your Arduino program to print a banner over the serial port at startup, do you see that banner when you open the Serial Monitor in the Arduino IDE?

Comment: Yes, I do. But as I said, it seems like the Arduino doesn't reboot when the Serial Port gets opened by the C# program. Maybe there's something wrong with it opening the port and that's the problem, after all? Would be strange that there is no error message then, though...